# MySQL AWS RDS instance size grows violently and unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, innodb

I've been investigating some strange behaviour in a client's AWS RDS instance (MySQL 5.7.26) running two databases. I'm not a DB engineer, so this is going over my head.

Over the year there have been 3 occurrences of the RDS instance size increasing in size over a 2h period. The bumps were in the `1GB` to `8GB` range. For perspective, the RDS instance has `60GB` allocated to it. [Here is a screenshot of the cloudwatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW60s.png) logs for one of these occurrences.

The two databases have the same schema, one is used for tests, the other for the live environment. They both consist of one main table of time series data. Here is the schema:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE timeSeriesTable;

'CREATE TABLE `timeSeriesTable` (
    `id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `device_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `server_timestamp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `modified` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `deleted` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `sensor_id` (`sensor_id`),
      KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`)
    )
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'
```

The live table statistics are as follows:

```
column_count: 6
table_rows: 88749947
data_length: 5.8GB
index_length: 8.3GB
```

There are many things that can be optimized here, but my main concern at the moment is avoiding future storage issues like these. Other notes:

- master logs were disabled at the time
- RDS performance insight are disabled
- the sum of the table sizes confirms the AWS storage estimates (leads me to think the problem is data related or MySQL related)
- there are two ways for data to get into the system, one is programmatic, the other requires user authentication
- number of rows for different time chunks is consistent, there are no abnormally large amounts of data at any point in time
- occurrences are not spaced evenly apart, so not a scheduled job
- I'm enabling query logging to potentially catch this in the act

**UPDATE**
After a DB reboot, the free storage magically increased by `8GB`.

Comment: How much RAM?  What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  I see that the table takes about 14GB on disk.  Where `SELECTs` were performed during the spike?

Comment: I see a column `device_id`, but an index on `sensor_id`.

Comment: @RickJames `innodb_buffer_pool_size` reads: `{DBInstanceClassMemory*3/4} 5242880-18446744073709551615`, on one of the occasions I can confirm a very large `SELECT` was running, RAM -> `16GB` and `sensor_id` and `device_id` are the same thing (my bad)

Comment: Instead, run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';`

Comment: I added to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure that there is anything that anyone can do to help with this problem. I have a number of possible suggestions however I'm not sure any of them will be able to be checked or verified through RDS alone:

1. Were any additional tables created manually? On the occasional chance that I ever have to perform manual DB alterations I often create a "backup" of the table before making any adjustments.
2. Were any additional indexes added? I can't remember for sure if indexes only take memory or also storage but I believe that additional indexes will take more storage regardless of if they are being actively used in memory.
3. You appear to only be looking at one table here. The storage will be affected by all tables in the database as well as other databases on the instance. Are you certain that this table has caused the issue?

It does look very much like additional data was being written to the database at the time. There is a spike in IOPS, latency and storage space.

How did you identify that there were no spikes in the volume of data written? If it was a query sharing it may help.

I'd really advise seeking professional support for this. I would definitely not recommend investigating anything on the database instance if you are not trained and confident in doing so.

In my experience tracing database problems is extremely difficult and I'm not sure anyone would be able to help you effectively without direct access to the database and monitoring which is something that you may struggle to be able to find here.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the cloud service was taking a backup?

You don't want to talk about optimization, but that could be the solution, or at least part of it.

`INT` takes 4 bytes; consider using a smaller datatype.

What is in the `id`?  Anything useful?  If not, let's discuss getting rid of it; it is bulky, both in the data's BTree and in both secondary indexes' BTrees.

If `(sensor_id, timestamp)` is unique, it would probably be better for it to be the `PRIMARY KEY`.  (That's a "composite" index; the order is important.)  This might help some `SELECTs` -- in performance and in how much they need to load into RAM to be performed.

I suspect a `SELECT` came along and scanned the entire table.  And only part of the table was in cache (the buffer_pool) before that.  This could easily explain a spike as the buffer pool grows.  There is a limit of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, but, I guess, it had not yet expanded to full size before the spike.

**More**

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` might be 12GB.  A table scan of that sensor data would suddenly expand the buffer pool if it was not already at 12GB.  The is normal.

Let's look at that big `SELECT` and see if we can make it less scary.